# Mysqli SELECT all that don't return from a array

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm building a back office for a website that has a client management system and they have a membership that has to be renewed every month.

At this point I have an array of all userId's that have paid last month and I want to query witch of them haven't paid yet.

Resuming : (1,2,3,4,5,6,7 and 8) have paid the membership on the last month, and this month only (1,2) have renewed. So I want to echo (3,4,5,6,7 and 8).

How can this be done in a single query? If it helps, the code I'm using is really similar to this:

```
SELECT userId FROM membership
    WHERE userId IN ($array) AND MONTH(payement) = MONTH(NOW())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your array is filled up with a query. Then you could use:

So you select all userid's who payed last month and the ones which are not in the query of this month (if that makes sence :-))

I suggest you use php to determine the month.
So your code would look like:

```
$previousMonth=date('m', strtotime(date('Y-m')." -1 month"));
$thisMonth=date('m');
$sql = "SELECT userId FROM membership WHERE MONTH(payement) =".$previousMonth. " AND userId NOT IN (SELECT userid FROM membership WHERE MONTH(payement) = ".$thisMonth.";";
```

Comment: worked like a charm with a minor modification!
[ WHERE MONTH(payement) = (MONTH(NOW()) -1) ]

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to convert your array into a string by using `implode()`:

```
<?php

    $str = implode(",",$array);
    $que = "SELECT userId FROM membership WHERE userId IN ($str) AND MONTH(payement) = MONTH(NOW())";

?>
```